# Replace image attributes for lazyload plugin on image elements with specific class

Tags: javascript, php, image, dom

I'm using WordPress and I want to apply lazy load to only certain images. I found here a way to create the data-src attributes and replace the src attribute with the correct image https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60792/replace-image-attributes-for-lazyload-plugin-data-src. Right now my code applies the lazy load to all the images, and I just want to apply it to the images with the class lazy-load.

This is how my code looks

```
// Lazyload Converter
function add_lazyload($content) {

$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);

$images = [];

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {
    $images[] = $node;
}

foreach ($images as $node) {
    $fallback = $node->cloneNode(true);

    $oldsrc = $node->getAttribute('src');
    $node->setAttribute('data-src', $oldsrc );
    $newsrc = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/placeholders/squares.svg';
    $node->setAttribute('src', $newsrc);

    $oldsrcset = $node->getAttribute('srcset');
    $node->setAttribute('data-srcset', $oldsrcset );
    $newsrcset = '';
    $node->setAttribute('srcset', $newsrcset);

    $noscript = $dom->createElement('noscript', '');
    $node->parentNode->insertBefore($noscript, $node);
    $noscript->appendChild($fallback);
}

$newHtml = preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $dom->saveHTML()));
return $newHtml;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_lazyload');
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'add_lazyload');
```

how can I get the element by class instead of using tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) (with [domxpath](/questions/tagged/domxpath)) for this; xpath is a query language to select nodes from XML/HTML documents.

Unfortunately, selecting elements which have a class that is the stand-alone phrase `lazy-load`, is a bit convoluted with xpath; it's not as concise as you may perhaps be accustomed to with [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors); xpath doesn't have shorthand attribute selectors like `@attr~="lazy-load"`, etc.

Here's an example of how you would select all `<img>` elements that have the class `lazy-load`:

```
// create a DOMXPath instance that operates on your DOMDocument instance $dom
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );

// select nodes by some criteria (returns a non-live¹ DOMNodeList)
$images = $xpath->query( '//img[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " lazy-load ")]' );

// then apply the same operations to the nodes again as in your last foreach loop
foreach ($images as $node) {
  $fallback = $node->cloneNode(true);
  // etc.
}
```

<sup>1) Although not officially documented anywhere (as far as I'm aware), the `DOMNodeList` returned by `DOMXPath` is not "live", as opposed to `DOMNodeList`s returned by `DOMDocument`, I believe. So, your first `foreach()` should be unnecessary. But you'd have to give it a try, to be sure.</sup>

I would advice against doing any of the following, but if you are sure the only class those `<img>` elements will ever have is `lazy-load`, i.e. the `class` attribute will always exactly be `lazy-load`, without any spaces and/or other classes, you could also use this, much simpler, query instead:

```
$images = $xpath->query( '//img[@class="lazy-load"]' );
```

or, if the `<img>` elements can have multiple classes, but will never have any other classes that contain the phrase `lazy-load` (like `class="thumbnail lazy-loading"`, for instance) you could use:

```
$images = $xpath->query( '//img[contains(@class,"lazy-load")]' );
```