# Extract href with DomDocuments

Tags: php, web-scraping, domdocument

I try to extract the href from a url with php's domDocument, example url is:

trovaprezzi.it/categoria.aspx?id=-1&libera=frigorifero+lg

And the URL I would like to extract is the one in 'Frigoriferi e Congelatori', this is my code sketch:

I should extract this link: 'trovaprezzi.it/prezzo_frigoriferi-congelatori_frigorifero_lg.aspx'; from the souce code $url, but the link change, for example in this page 'trovaprezzi.it/categoria.aspx?id=-1&libera=lavatrice+lg'‌​; i need to extract the first link: 'trovaprezzi.it/prezzo_lavatrici-asciugatrici_lavatrice_lg.aspx';

```
$url = 'http://www.trovaprezzi.it/categoria.aspx?id=-1&libera=frigorifero+lg';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('/html/body/div[@class="catsMI"]/div')->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href')  ;
echo $nodes;
```

Thanks in advance for the help

UPDATE 23/06

Code example where I want to extract the Link:

```
<div class="catsMI">
        <div><a title="confronta i prezzi Frigoriferi e Congelatori" href="/prezzo_frigoriferi-congelatori_frigorifero_lg.aspx">Frigoriferi e Congelatori</a><span>(732 prezzi)</span></div>
        <div><a title="confronta i prezzi Ricambi Elettrodomestici" href="/prezzo_ricambi-elettrodomestici_frigorifero_lg.aspx">Ricambi Elettrodomestici</a><span>(191 prezzi)</span></div>
</div>
```

And i want this URL:

```
/prezzo_frigoriferi-congelatori_frigorifero_lg.aspx
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, what are you actually asking for help with?

Comment: I should extract this link: 'http://www.trovaprezzi.it/prezzo_frigoriferi-congelatori_frigorifero_lg.aspx' from the souce code $url, but the link change, for example in this page 'http://www.trovaprezzi.it/categoria.aspx?id=-1&libera=lavatrice+lg' i need to extract the first link: 'http://www.trovaprezzi.it/prezzo_lavatrici-asciugatrici_lavatrice_lg.aspx'.

Comment: Don't tell me, add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

[`DOMXPath::query()`](https://php.net/manual/domxpath.query.php) returns a [`DOMNodeList`](https://php.net/manual/class.domnodelist.php) which doesn't have a method `getElementsByTagName()`. Only [`DOMDocument`](https://php.net/manual/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) and [`DOMElement`](https://php.net/manual/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php) have that method.

I haven't looked at the page you've given (please add a minimal workable sample of the site's HTML to your question), but try this:

```
// search for all <a> elements that have a href attribute
// which are descendants of //div[@class="catsMI"]/div
$nodes = $xpath->query( '//div[@class="catsMI"]/div//a[@href]' );

// check if we found any nodes...
if( $nodes->length > 0 ) {
   // if we did: get href attribute of the first node we found
   $href = $nodes->item( 0 )->getAttribute( 'href' );
   echo $href;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately it still does not work, I added an example of HTML in the first post!

Comment: @JustLazzah Okay, I've changed the query. Try it again now. If it still doesn't work then test that the HTML is actually loaded into the `DOMDocument` by viewing the output of `$dom->saveHTML();`. If that's working fine, then the only thing I can think of is that `catsMI` is not the only, exact value of the `class` attribute. In that case, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44353414), about that issue.

Comment: @JustLazzah Okay, good to hear and you're welcome. Good luck.